# End dialog Proactively

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want to end a dialog for a particular user proactively. I see APIs to send message and start a dialog proactively using the address of the conversation. Is there any API to end a current/particular dialog for that conversation (preferably using the address of the conversation) proactively. I am using the **bot builder Node.js SDK**.

This is required to provide a manual intervention for the chat admin. I don't want to just end the whole conversation (there is an API to end the conversation as well), but assist the user on something.

*All the APIs mentioned can be found [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to leverage [`loadSession(address: IAddress, callback: (err: Error, session: Session) => void): void;`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L4103), then end the conversion in the callback function. Please refer to following code snippet:

```
let savedAddress;

server.get('/api/CustomWebApi', function (req, res, next) {
    bot.loadSession(savedAddress, (err, session) => {
        if (!err) {
            session.send('ternimal this conversion')
            session.endConversation();
        }
    })
    res.send('triggered');
    next();
});

bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
        savedAddress = session.message.address;
        message = 'You can terminate the conversation by accessing: ';
        message += 'http://localhost:' + server.address().port + '/api/CustomWebApi';
        session.send(message);
    }
])
```

Comment: I somehow, overlooked the `loadSession` API. That was the clue. Otherwise I was thinking of using the `receive` API, which mimics sending a message to the bot, which would have triggered the session.endDialog on the conversation!

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js bots, you can always end a dialog using the session variable, i.e

```
session.endDialog();
```

See bot builder SDK [session](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html) references. You can also 'chain' these methods, i.e do something like...

```
session.send('proactiveMessage').endDialog();
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: I want to end session proactively. Proactive messages are sent using `bot.send("this is a message", IAddresss)`. There is no session object available when sending proactive messages. Session object represents current conversation. Proactive messages are used to send messages to a different conversation. This is __not__ a right answer.